# JQuery Select based on multiple children values

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I need to select a div (with a class of data) from my page, where one child has a particular value (Test1), and another child has another value (User1);

For instance, I want to select `div.data` in this example (Note User1 in `div.user`)

```
<div class="data">
    <div>
      <div class="details">
        Test1
      </div>
      <div class="user">User1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But not this (Note User2 in `div.user`):

```
<div class="data">
    <div>
      <div class="details">Test1</div>
      <div class="user">User2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to write a query using `:has`, but It either selects both divs, or neither.

```
$("div.data:has(div.details:contains('Test1'), div.user.contains('User1'))")
```

How would I write a query to get `div.data` in this situation?

**Clarification:** I wasn't originally clear, but I need to select `div.data` When the user div contains "User1" *and* the details div contains the value "Test1". i.e. *Both* conditions must be true for `div.data` to be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think contains is the best fit for the use case, still try

```
$('div.data:has(div.details:contains("Test1")):not(:has(.user:contains("User2")))').css('color', 'red')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rKMQ4/)

---

```
$('div.data').filter(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    return $.trim($this.find('.details').text()) == 'Test1' && $.trim($this.find('.user').text()) != 'User2'
}).css('color', 'red')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NuH6C/)

Comment: That might work, however User2 could be any other value apart from User1. i.e. There are many users, but I'm only interested in a particular one (for now)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".data").find("div.user:contains('User1')").parents("div.data")
```

*Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/LvJ7Z/1/

Your requirement is to only select the `div`s which are having a class `user` (descendents of `div` with the class `data`) which contain the text "*User1*". Remember, `contains` is case-sensitive.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify, but I need when *both* the user div has User1 *and* the details div contains "Test1"

Answer (score 0):

You should try considering adding classes to your data, so that way you can *actually* select data that you need.

If you still want to approach this way, best to do it with this:

```
$('.data').each(function(){

    var thisData = $(this);

    // Uncomment if you want to find by specific siblings

    if($('.user:contains(\'User1\')', thisData).length)
    //if($('.details .details', thisData).length)
    {
        // Do whatever as you like
        thisData.css('background', 'green');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fjsYc/)

Comment: Unfortunately the page is not under my (I'm writing a Chrome content_script extension), so I can only work with what is there.

Comment: Additionally, I've updated the question with a clarification.